# ¿Cómo comprobar que el usuario inserto una url?

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando en una red social y al momento que el usuario comenta una dirección `url` me lo toma como un simple comentario .

Quisiera que cuando pusiera una dirección `url` allí esta al darle `click` te lleve a esa dirección.

Por ejemplo en `facebook` un usuario manda un `url` por chat y al darle `click` te lleva a esa página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías empezar por validar que el `String` ingresado sea una `URL`. Puedes usar `filter_var()`:

```
if (filter_var($textoIngresadoPorUsuario, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
   echo "Es una URL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos aprovechar ciertos patrones en las url's, por ejemplo el uso de `www`, `http`, `https` para detectar una posible url:

```
<?php
$texto = "es un comentario con una url https://es.stackoverflow.com de prueba";
$temp = explode(" ",$texto);
$new = array();
foreach ($temp as $key => $word):
    if ( filter_var($word, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ):
        $new[] = "<a href='".$word."'>".$word."<a/>";
    else:
        $new[] = $word;
    endif;
endforeach;
$texto = implode(" ", $new);
echo $texto;
?>
```

O podemos usar [filter_var()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp) para validar:

```
<?php
$texto = "es un comentario con una url https://es.stackoverflow.com de prueba";
$temp = explode(" ",$texto);
$new = array();
foreach ($temp as $key => $word):
    if ( !(strpos($word, 'www') === false) || !(strpos($word, 'http') === false)  ):
        $new[] = "<a href='".$word."'>".$word."<a/>";
    else:
        $new[] = $word;
    endif;
endforeach;
$texto = implode(" ", $new);
echo $texto;
?>
```